# Error when trying to add member or owner to Team using Graph Api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

When trying to add a member or owner to an existing Team I'm getting the following error:

> "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities"

Here are the PowerShell commands that I'm running:

```
$addMemberUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/groups/$clonedTeamId/owners/$ref"
$addMemberBody = [PSCustomObject]@{
     "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/1.0/users/$userId"
}
$addMemberBody = $addMemberBody | ConvertTo-Json
$addMemberResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Header -Uri $addMemberUri -Method POST -body $addMemberBody -ContentType 'application/json'
```

My application has the following permissions in Azure AD:

> Group.Read.All, 
>   Group.ReadWrite.All, 
>   User.ReadWrite.All,

Get requests are working, but adding members or owners fails with the aforementioned error every time.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write requests are only supported on contained entities, Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959752/write-requests-are-only-supported-on-contained-entities-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this issue. I needed to add a backtick in front of $ref in the $addMemberUri variable:

```
$addMemberUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/groups/$clonedTeamId/owners/`$ref"
```

After adding the backtick the command ran successfully.